# The conventional way of exporting many to many relation in a single csv file

Tags: database, csv

I have a database which has the following many to many relation:

Group table:

```
group_id | group_name
```

User table:

```
user_id | user_name
```

User_group table:

```
user_id | group_id
```

I want to create a single csv file that will incorporate those 3 tables. I can ignore the ids from database. The csv should be easily parseable in order to recreate the database with the same data. I am thinking about the format that csv should have. Right now my idea is to do the following

```
user_name | group
-------------------
bob       | group_a
          | group_b
sam       | group_a
```

However, I am not sure what is more conventional to do. Maybe list all the groups separated by comma/space?

Comment: If you create the csv to _be easily parseable in order to recreate the database with the same data_, one user and group per line is easier to process later.